# If W is a subspace of V then $W^⊥$ is a subspace of $V^⊥$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe this to be false.

As it seems that $V^⊥$ is a subspace of $W^⊥$ instead, but can someone explain more in depth?

Comment: The order reverses!

Comment: It's always good to have an example in mind for this sort of thing. For example, take $W$ to be the $x$-axis and $V$ to be the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $W^{\perp}$ is the $yz$-plane and $V^{\perp}$ is the $z$-axis, so $V^{\perp} \subseteq W^{\perp}$. You can then use this intuition to guide a proof of the more general fact that $$W \le V \quad \Rightarrow \quad V^{\perp} \le W^{\perp}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $W\subseteq V$, then any vector orthogonal to $V$ will for sure also be orthogonal to $W$, therefore $V^\perp\subseteq W^\perp$. The space orthogonal to $V$ is smaller, because its elements have to be orthogonal to "more" vectors, i.e. the condition is stronger.

Answer (score 1):

$W^\perp$ is the set of vectors $w$ that are orthogonal to all the vectors in $W$, and similarly for $V^\perp$ and $V$.  If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then for a vector to be in $V^\perp$ it must satisfy all the conditions that are required for $W^\perp$ (i.e. being orthogonal to all the vectors in $W$, since those are also in $V$) plus  additional conditions (being orthogonal to any vectors that are in $V$ but not in $W$).  So $V^\perp$ is contained in $W^\perp$, not the other way (in general).